# filtering Tree with linq

Tags: c#, linq, filter, tree

I have this structure:

```
public class issue
{
    public int ID {get; set;}
    public int? ParentID {get; set;}
    public string Type {get;set;}
    public List<issue> Children {get;set;}
}
```

and my tree is:

```
parent1 ={ID = 1,
           ParentID = null,
           Type = "Category",
           Children = {children1 = {ID = 2,
                       ParentID = 1,
                       Type = "Project",
                        Children = {children2 = {ID = 3,
                                                ParentID = 2,
                                                Type = "Action",
                                                Children = null}}},
                                    {children3 = {ID = 4,
                                                  ParentID = 1,
                                                  Type = "Action",
                                                  Children = null}}}
parent2 = {ID = 5,
           ParentID = null,
           Type = "Category",
           Children = {children4 = {ID = 6,
                                    ParentID = 5,
                                    Type = "Action",
                                    Children = null}}}
parent3 = {ID = 7,
            ParentID = null,
            Type = "Project",
            Children = {children5 = {ID = 8,
                                    ParentID = 7,
                                    Type = "Action",
                                    Children = null}}}
```

I need to filter this tree in this way that at first level appear only the parents that fulfill the filter plus thous children that are not includen in the parents tree, for example, I want to filter for Type: "Category" and "Action", the tree result most be:

```
parent1 ={ID = 1,
           ParentID = null,
           Type = "Category",
           Children = {children1 = {ID = 2,
                       ParentID = 1,
                       Type = "Project",
                        Children = {children2 = {ID = 3,
                                                ParentID = 2,
                                                Type = "Action",
                                                Children = null}}},
                                    {children3 = {ID = 4,
                                                  ParentID = 1,
                                                  Type = "Action",
                                                  Children = null}}}
parent2 = {ID = 5,
           ParentID = null,
           Type = "Category",
           Children = {children4 = {ID = 6,
                                    ParentID = 5,
                                    Type = "Action",
                                    Children = null}}}
parent3 = {ID = 8,
            ParentID = 7,
            Type = "Action",
            Children = null}}
```

there is any way to do this using LINQ?

Comment: `tree.Where(p => p.Type == "Category" || p.Type == "Action")` ?

Comment: LINQ is not very well suited for hierarchical data. Try something else.

Comment: Matias that's not the correct answer, the idea is when a child fulfill the condition but not the father, the child most be at the level of the father, this behavior will be just for the first level, the other levels remain equals.